# How to execute JSON config file at run time react js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, single-page-application

I want to achieve Externalization of all text and images in react. It means i just change in my json file and it will reflect with my live webapp(SPA). for that i have make on json file like.

```
     {
      "signup.validation.invalid.email": "Email is invalid",
      "signup.validation.require.email": "Email is required",
      "signup.validation.long.email": "Email is too long",
      "signup.validation.short.email": "Email is too short",
       ............
      }
```

i have name this file as en-us.json. and imports in my app.js like

```
  import {translations} from "./i18n/translations";

   export const translations = {
   "en-US": require('./../../public/en-US')
    }
```

so any one can help how can i achieve externalization?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state for language which user choose for entire web app. When user select language, you setState() with new language from `translations`